# Expanding a CSS grid area into another grid area when the latter is empty

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following simple grid setup. It works as intended in situations where there are both `content` and `sidebar` divs present, but I would however like the `content` area to expand to fill the area left by `sidebar` when a `sidebar` area is not present on the page. In the second grid in the example below, `sidebar` is not present but the `content` area does not expand to fill up the left over space. I would like it to do so.

```css
/* Based on example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas */

.content {
    grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
    grid-area: side;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "main side"
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<!-- First grid - works fine -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>

<!-- Second grid - content should expand to fill the area that would be used by sidebar -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Perhaps this is a case where I shouldn't be using CSS grid for this, but rather floats?

Comment: a single parent container is to be used for the grid, then you can set children inside the grid wherever you want.

Comment: look examples at **Leaving a grid cell empty** then **Spanning multiple cells** to understand what you do wrong ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to use grid-area, flexbox gives intended result. No need to use float.

```css
/* Based on example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas */

.content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.sidebar {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<!-- First grid - works fine -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>

<!-- Second grid - content should expand to fill the area that would be used by sidebar -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're wrapper contains two columns which are specified in:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Both columns are 1fr wide (1 fraction of a total of 2)

Deleting one of the divs inside will not expand the other since it is still 1 of two fractions wide.

Remove one of the columns in the grid will fix your issue:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
```

As a sidenote, since your wrapper now only contains a single div inside it makes no sense for it to be a grid.